# dma_alloc_coherent() and physical addresses

Tags: drivers

The DMA-API-HOWTO document says that dma_alloc_coherent() returns two values: the virtual address which you can use to access it from the CPU and `dma_handle` which you pass to the card.

Shouldn't the virtual address and the `dma_handle` map to the same physical address? That is not what I see.

Is it expected that the `dma_handle` is the same as its physical address?

I am using a x86_64 system with the IOMMU enabled. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04, and the kernel is 4.15.0-47-generic.

My code:

```
ret = dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64));

dmabuffp = dma_alloc_coherent (dev_ptr, (size_t)4*1024*1024, &dma_hndl, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);

printk(KERN_INFO "init: dma_hndl = 0x%llX\n", dma_hndl);<br />
printk(KERN_INFO "init: dmabuffp VA = 0x%llX\n", (uint64_t)dmabuffp);<br />
printk(KERN_INFO "init: dma_hndl VA = 0x%llX\n", (uint64_t)bus_to_virt(dma_hndl));

printk(KERN_INFO "init: dmabuffp PA = 0x%010llX\n", (uint64_t)virt_to_phys(dmabuffp));<br />
printk(KERN_INFO "init: dma_hndl PA = 0x%010llX\n",(uint64_t)virt_to_phys(bus_to_virt(dma_hndl)));
```

After the module loads, `dmesg` shows this:

```
init: dma_hndl = 0xFFC00000<br />
init: dmabuffp VA = 0xFFFF888E9B000000<br />
init: dma_hndl VA = 0xFFFF88873FC00000<br />
init: dmabuffp PA = 0x085B000000<br />
init: dma_hndl PA = 0x00FFC00000
```

The device can write and read using `dma_hndl`, but the value it writes is not at *buffptr.

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Additional testing shows that `dma_hndl` does map to the same physical address as `dmabuffp`.  Apparently `virt_to_phys(bus_to_virt(dma_hndl))` does not resolve as expected and instead is circular, returning the original `dma_hndl` value instead of the physical address that is mapped by the IOMMU.

Answer (score 0):

The `dma_addr_t` is an I/O virtual address (IOVA), it's the address the device uses to access the buffer returned by `dma_alloc_coherent`.

```
void * dma_alloc_coherent(struct device *dev, 
                          size_t size, 
                          dma_addr_t *dma_handle, 
                          gfp_t flag)
```

> The reason `dma_addr_t` is not same as `virt_to_phys(dmabuffp)` is because IOMMU is enabled.

Only the device uses the `dma_addr_t` for DMA access. The processor accesses need to use the returned `void*`, or some sort of `virt_to_phys()` version of that to allow userspace to mmap it through devmem.

Without an IOMMU, the `dma_addr_t` is simply a `virt_to_phy()`/`virt_to_bus()` translation of the `void*` buffer, so it can be used for processor access directly but it is incorrect usage of the DMA API.